# Python pandas dataframe, aggregating row by row up to stopping criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I would like to sum over specific rows within a column and create a new dataframe with the aggregated values only.
E.g., the original frame looks like (with A=ID, B=datum [yyyymmdd], C=hour+min [hhmm], D=value)

```
    A         B     C    D
11035  20190101  0010  1.1
11035  20190101  0020  1.9
11035  20190101  0030  3.3
11035  20190101  0040  1.0
11035  20190101  0050  2.9
11035  20190101  0100  0.5
11001  20190109  0110  0.0
11001  20190109  0120  0.2
11001  20190109  0130  1.5
11001  20190109  0140  1.2
11001  20190109  0150  1.9
11001  20190109  0200  4.5
.
.
.
```

The final dataframe should include only those rows at full hour (i.e., 0100, 0200, ...) but the values should contain the sum of the previous 6 values (e.g. for 0100: sum from 0010 to 0100).
The output data frame of the example above should then look:

```
    A         B     C     D
11035  20190101  0100  10.7
11001  20190109  0200   9.3
.
.
.
```

How to code this exercise most effectively?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: What do you want to do with the ID column `A`? Should the df be grouped by the `A` column in the first place and then by `C` afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better approach as suggested by @roganjosh -Thanks

```
df_new=df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C': 'max', 'D': 'sum'}).reset_index().sort_values('C')
print(df_new)

    A         B     C     D
11035  20190101  0100  10.7
11001  20190109  0200   9.3
```

**EDIT per question in the answer**

```
df.groupby(['A','B',(df.C%100==0).cumsum().shift().fillna(0)]).\
agg({'D':'sum','C':lambda x: x[x%100==0]}).reset_index(level=[0,1]).sort_values('A',ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
       A         B     D    C
0  11035  20190101  10.7  100
1  11035  20190101   7.7  200
2  11001  20190109   9.3  200
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `df.groupby(['A','B']).agg({'C': 'max', 'D': 'sum'}).reset_index()`? I'm not seeing why this takes two `groupby`s and a merge

Comment: Nope, feel free to update. That chain of operations is at best unwieldy

Comment: It works for the lines given by the example, but for larger datasets, it seems not to work properly: so e.g., if the frame is:           A         B    C     D
    0  11001  20190109  200   9.3
    1  11035  20190101  200  21.4
then my output is:

       A         B    C     D
   0  11001  20190109  200   9.3
   1  11035  20190101  200  18.4
but it should be:

       A         B    C     D
   0  11035  20190101  100  10.7
   1  11035  20190101  200   7.7
   2  11001  20190109  200   9.3

Comment: @akann check EDIT

Answer (score 0):

It works for the lines given by the example, but for larger datasets, it seems not to work properly:
so e.g., if the frame is:

```
    A         B     C    D
11035  20190101  0010  1.1
11035  20190101  0020  1.9
11035  20190101  0030  3.3
11035  20190101  0040  1.0
11035  20190101  0050  2.9
11035  20190101  0100  0.5
11035  20190101  0110  1.1
11035  20190101  0120  1.9
11035  20190101  0130  0.3
11035  20190101  0140  1.0
11035  20190101  0150  2.9
11035  20190101  0200  0.5
11001  20190109  0110  0.0
11001  20190109  0120  0.2
11001  20190109  0130  1.5
11001  20190109  0140  1.2
11001  20190109  0150  1.9
11001  20190109  0200  4.5
```

then my output is:

```
       A         B    C     D
0  11001  20190109  200   9.3
1  11035  20190101  200  18.4
```

but it should be:

```
       A         B    C     D
0  11035  20190101  100  10.7
1  11035  20190101  200   7.7
2  11001  20190109  200   9.3
```

So the groupby - condition should be extended to the column C where the values of C are all within the last hour...